# How to setup different persistence options at the same time in Redis

Tags: redis, persistence

I would like to know if it's possible to configure two different Redis database with different persistence options at the same time:

eg:

```
redis db 0 => appendonly=no
redis db 1 => appendonly=yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO, you CANNOT do that. Instead, you should launch two Redis instances, and config each instance with different persistence option.